# MS SQL Agent fails with domain account fails to restart MSSQLSERVER Service (2008R2 Standard)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I recently was asked to bring a new SQL server online. Having no experience with this I of course did quite a bit of research on best practices. The install went without any issues with the exception of the following:

Per:[Reference](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2008/03/sql-server-2005-setup-checklist-part-1-before-the-install/) (Many other sources sited the same practice)

I installed MSSQL Server with a domain service accounts for both the agent and db service. Both services start correctly upon boot. I setup alerts and decided to test them. Upon killing the sqlservr.exe through task manager, the agent fails to restart the service.

Reviewing the logs I found this error:

```
[368] AutoRestart: Unable to restart the MSSQLSERVER service (reason: Access is denied)
```

Upon failing to restart 3 times, the SQL Agent itself shuts down.

The service users have no admin rights, but from my research SQL 2008 R2 is designed to run least privileged. I'm would really like to avoid giving the agent local admin rights.

I assumed(I know) the SQL installer did some magic to make this work upon install.

The best idea of a solution so far is to modify the SDDL outlined [here](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/allow_windows_users_to_restart_service/)

Any advise would be appreciated.

Software:

SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard
MS Win2k8R2 Datacenter SP1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user has ownership of the database files themselves.